# A simple question on Ext groups

Tags: homological-algebra, group-extensions

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Is $\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}(G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ trivial? If not, under what condition is it trivial?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ a trivial $G$-module?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. Both $G$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ are considered as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an abelian group. The following are equivalent: 
1. $A$ is [divisible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group). 
2. $A$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module. 
3. $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}^i(G,A) = 0$ for every abelian group $G$.

Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is a divisible group and since divisibility is preserved under taking quotients, $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ is also divisible.

Comment: You are right. I totally forgot about these. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know who answered the first, but let me accept Cihan's answer as he explaine the detail.